# How to group 2 groups into 1 group in Extjs grid?

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs5

I have this grid and would like to group 2 groups into a **single group** based on the status. Basically I want to put together **"Cheched-In"** and **"Ready for MA"** into a single group. Thanks a lot for the help!

**Here's the working code:** [**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/henrygranados/0dgv1cfk/1/)

```
Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', {
title: 'Employees',
store: store,
 columns: [
  { text: 'Box', dataIndex: 'box', width: 50 },
  { text: 'Name', dataIndex: 'name', flex: 2 },
  { text: 'Status', dataIndex: 'status', flex: 1 }
],
features: [{ftype:'grouping'}],
renderTo: Ext.getBody()
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to have a different field for grouping, try this

```
function addGroupField(data) {
  return data.map(function(row) {
    return {
      box: row.box,
      name: row.name,
      status: row.status,
      groupedStatus: [
        'Checked-In',
        'Ready for MA'
      ].indexOf(row.status) > -1 ? 'Checked-In & Ready for MA' : row.status,
    }
  });
}

var data = addGroupField([
  { box: '', name: 'Brady, Marsha',status: 'Checked-In' },
  { box: 'MA', name: 'Dwight, Schrute', status: 'With MA' },
  { box: 'MA', name: 'Jim, Halpert', status: 'With MA' },
  { box: 'MA', name: 'Mike, Brown', status: 'With MA' },
  { box: 'MA', name: 'Steve, Smith', status: 'With MA' },
  { box: 'MA', name: 'Lori, Morrison', status: 'With MA' },
  { box: 'MA', name: 'Mary, Loson', status: 'With MA' },
  { box: 'MA', name: 'Junior, Meloni', status: 'With MA' },
  { box: 'MA', name: 'Jim, Halpert', status: 'With MA' },
  { box: '', name: 'Kevin, Malone', status: 'Checked-In' },
  { box: '', name: 'Angela, Martin', status: 'Checked-In' },
  { box: '2', name: 'Jim, Halpert', status: 'Ready for MA' },
  { box: '2', name: 'Kevin, Malone', status: 'Ready for MA' },
  { box: '2', name: 'Angela, Martin', status: 'Ready for MA' }
]);

var store = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
  fields: ['name', 'seniority', 'department'],
  groupField: 'groupedStatus',
  data: data
});

Ext.onReady(function() {
  Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', {
    title: 'Employees',
    store: store,
    columns: [
      { text: 'Box', dataIndex: 'box', width: 50 },
      { text: 'Name', dataIndex: 'name', flex: 2 },
      { text: 'Status', dataIndex: 'status', flex: 1 }
    ],
    features: [{ftype:'grouping'}],
    renderTo: Ext.getBody()
  });
});
```

Comment: it worked! Is there a way to also add a group title on the right side of each of the groups like "TEAM FIRST" and for the second group "TEAM SECOND" ? I would like to have the title at the same level as the "Checked-In & Ready for MA" ttitle but on the right side

Comment: You can actually put html inside field values so you can try something like this `Checked-In & Ready for MA<div style="float: right">TEAM FIRST</div>` for example

Comment: Sure bue you will need to update your question though so other people don't get confused